# Why does my code keep waiting for user input

Tags: java

Ok so I have a text file like so

**dears fears**

**heart heart**

**sail ruin**

**etc**

I'm trying to run the scanner through each line so I can
create a WordLadder object which requires the 2 strings in each line.

```
try {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
   String s = sc.next();
   String s2 = sc.next();
   WordLadder wl = new WordLadder(s, s2);
   System.out.print(wl.toString());
}
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
   System.out.print("File not found");
}
```

For some reason, when I run the debugger, as far as I can tell, it runs through once then it waits for user input. It creates a word ladder with dears and fears and prints the solution for that word ladder. Then second loop it waits for user input instead of doing it again.

I'm thoroughly confused because when I do something like this

```
try {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
   while (sc.hasNext()) {
   String s = sc.next();
   System.out.println(s);
}
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
{
   System.out.print("File not found");
}
```

It prints all the words. But any variation I tried of trying to put those words in a wordladder object it waits for user input. Any ideas?

Comment: You are reading 2 lines per iteration in your loop so my guess is that you have an odd number of lines in your file which means the last `sc.next()` expects the input to come from System.in instead.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I don't think that's the issue. It only goes through the first line then waits for input

Comment: Is there a difference between

System.out.print(wl.toString()); and 
System.out.println(s);

Comment: @Xammax Yes word ladder to string prints out the finished word ladder and the word ladder needs 2 strings for the constructor

Comment: Yes sorry, I misread the question somewhat. Maybe you need to do `sc.nextLine()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code and I have no issues unless I have a file with an odd number of Strings. In that case, I get the following error:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1478)
    at Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

This is expected since you are reading 2 Strings for each `sc.hasNext()`.

So it seems to me that the issue might be the content of your `input.txt` file.